# Java socket timeout

Tags: java, сокет

[Проект](https://github.com/VyacheslavMartynenko/NetworkLab2)

В общем вот ссылка на проект, реализована игра быки-коровы:
сервер генерирует "слово" из 4 цифр, а клиент пытается его отгадать. Налажено подключение и отключение. Но не могу реализовать тайм аут, если пользователь или сервер долгое время не получали сообщений.
Максимум что удавалось, это в контроллере Клиента вызывать в методе нажатия кнопки после считывая данных функцию setOutTimeout, или которая бы сверяла System.currentMills заданную перед проверкой и после, все в целом отрабатывает и закрывает сокет, но появляется ошибка в Моделе: Stream closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, реализовал как смог, с помощью костылей.

```
class TimeoutThread extends Thread {
    private final int time;
    private boolean isStop = false;

    public TimeoutThread(int time) {
        super();
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void stopCheckTimeout() {
        this.isStop = true;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("start");
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + time;
            count = time / 1000;
            while (!isStop) {
                count--;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("ooo");
                ClientPresenter.getInstance().handleResult(String.valueOf(count));
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() > endTime) {
                    System.out.println("disc");
                    disconnect();
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("finish");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

И использовал:

```
new Thread(() -> {
        TimeoutThread timeoutThread = new TimeoutThread(10000);
        while (status) {
            try {
                if (isReceive()) {
                    timeoutThread.stopCheckTimeout(); //stop current timeout
                    boolean gameFinished = check();
                    if(gameFinished) {
                        return;
                    }

                    timeoutThread = new TimeoutThread(10000); // start new
                    timeoutThread.start();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                status = false;
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: может добавите код программы на вопрос? нажмите ссылку "Править"

Comment: Могу добавить, но его очень много, а ссылку на проект я дал в самом начале, менялся только один класс Client.